# Alternative way to Interact with Microsoft Office 365 server

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, smtp, email-client

My workplace has an Microsoft Office 365 and an "Outlook only" design philosophy wrt e-mail clients. As a long-standing user of emacs and mu I find the idea of using Outlook unbearable.
I have asked if they could [allow Davmail to interact with their server](https://github.com/mguessan/davmail/issues/71), or if there was any other alternative e-mail client that I could use, but received only negative responses.

Only the IT services have administrative rights, and the image below shows the standard user configuration of apps with permission to interact with the server.

[image]

Note that `IMAP` is allowed, and therefore I am able to download emails, but not of sending them (due to the unchecked `Authenticated SMTP` option). This is the key issue.

Given the above, my question is if there is any way of accessing and sending emails via a server configured in this way, and if so how? Thank you in advance.

Other notes: They use OAuth2 and the [standard configuration for O365 servers](https://otago.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3608/%7E/setting-up-thunderbird-mail-for-microsoft-365-post-migration). I normally use mbsync and msmtp along with mu (I'm on linux) but don't mind using any other mail sync package as long as it gets the job done.

**Update**

Using the Microsoft provided test page at: https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com returns the following [results](http://filedropper.com/jf0St382) (edited to avoid leaking personal information).

Comment: Use Control Panel to set up Outlook Mail.  Control Panel, Mail.

Comment: So are they using Exchange 2007 or are they using O365?

Comment: @user1686 Good point. I think that it is a mixture of both? I am not totally sure to be honest :-(. I have updated my question to provide results of a connectivity test. I hope it helps answer your question.

Comment: Exchange 2007 does not support OAuth 2. Furthermore, Exchange 2007 is EOL and has been since 2017. // If you don’t want to work with Outlook (or Outlook Web Access, which is very good nowadays) but your employer requires it, you know what to do.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks. Then probably that is just a legacy app in their system. I don't want to argue over if an email client is good or bad. I just find that restricting email access to a single email client is short-sighted (or even indicates lobbying from MS) and am looking for a viable alternative. As said above, I can at least download the emails via IMAP on Thunderbird. It is just the sending of email that is not working.

Comment: See if this helps : [How to Configure Thunderbird for Office 365 Using IMAP (Oauth2)](https://uit.stanford.edu/service/office365/configure/thunderbird-oauth2).

Comment: thanks @harrymc. With this setup I can receive emails but cannot send them, because of the `Authenticated SMTP` option mentioned above. Thunderbird returns a `Login to myworkplace account failed`, `Login to server smtp.office365.com with username myname@myworkplace.com failed.`

Comment: I have found a Microsoft post on this: Thunderbird Can not send email

Comment: @Ajned: Regarding discovery results, I *suspect* the `<UMUrl>` tag says "UM2007Legacy" because it is only provided _for_ Exchange 2007 systems (perhaps newer versions look at a different tag or don't use it at all), but the whole service seems to be unambiguously O365.

Comment: @user1686 Great to know. At least now I can scrap Exchange off the table and focus on O365.

Comment: @Ajned: The other way around – O365 is Exchange-based, so to talk to it you'd primarily use either Exchange Web Services API or older RPC MAPI, but either way the same stuff as with on-premises Exchange (aside from OAuth2 requirement, of course).

Comment: Sometimes O365 won't let you send if it thinks your password is too weak.

Comment: Other comments describe problems with the installation of Thunderbird. I suggest to uninstall Thunderbird, boot in Safe mode and reinstall.

Comment: @harrymc hmmm, interesting. I did not try either of those options: creating a stronger password or to uninstall thunderbird, botting in safe mode and reinstalling. Will give it a try and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by using [davmail](https://davmail.sourceforge.net/) in o365 Interactive. The DUO security system that I had to get through had a bug which prevented davmail's "o365 Interactive" mode to work, but that fortunately has [recently been fixed](https://community.duo.com/t/duo-web-v4-sdk-compatibility-with-javafx-webview/13075/4). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have found a Microsoft post on this: [Thunderbird Can not send email](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/thunderbird-can-not-send-email/b6653b44-8852-4aa9-9153-a165c7be983e?page=2#:%7E:text=my%20Thunderbird%20sends%20mail!)

Here is a solution:
You must be an Office 365 admin. Open the Microsoft 365 Admin Center (web page) and go to Users > Active users. Select the user, in the properties of the user panel click Mail. In the Email apps section, click Manage email apps.

In this panel, you have several items like Outlook on the web, Mobile (Exchange ActiveSync), POP, IMAP, Authenticated SMTP, …
All items were checked for me.
Uncheck the Authenticated SMTP item, then click on Save.
Check back the Authenticated SMTP item, then click on Save.

Wait a moment (30 sec for me) and the problem is solved: sending email with SMTP is working with Thunderbird.

Hope this can help you!

Comment: This would work IF I had administrative rights, but as stated above "Only the IT services have administrative rights" :-S. I keep scratching my head, wondering what is so special about the way how Outlook interacts with the O365 server? Can't it be somehow emulated with a Thunderbird add-on?